# Mvc 2 - ActionLink Create new Id and pass to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

In my database i have Books and RentBooks. I created a View for Books where the Index return a list of all books that have been created. What i would like to do now is following:

I have a ActionLink that says Rent Book.
When the user presses "Rent Book" it should create a rent for this. 
I don't know how to implement this.

This is what I tried to do: This is in de Index View of Books

```
 <%: Html.ActionLink("Rent Book", "RentBooks", "Book", new { id=item.RentBooks.Select(r=>r.RentId)}, null)%>
```

I have this in my BookController:

```
 public ActionResult RentBooks (int id)
 {
     db.RentBooks.Where(rb => rb.RentId == id).FirstOrDefault();
     return View();
 }
```

Maybe I'm missthinking something ... would i need to do this in my RoleController? Within the Index of Books I can't call

```
item.RentBooks.RentId
```

Answer (score 0):

You said *When the user presses "Rent Book" it should create a rent for this* in such case you should add/insert a new `RentBook` record to your DB. Then the code changes to be

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Rent Book", "RentBooks", "Book", new { new RentBook {id = 123, name="ddd"} }, null)%>

 public ActionResult RentBooks (RentBooks rb)
 {
     db.RentBooks.Add(rb);
     return View();
 }
```

Comment: All of my code happens within the Books Model ... so i cant say in the Index of Books `new RentBook`